# Convert a text column to a datetime column

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery, m

How do I convert a column of type text to type date/time?  I have the `createdon` column that I convert from UTC time to eastern time zone with day light savings time in consideration.  This works.  However, the `createon` column results in a type text.  I need it in date and time.
Below is my SQL query.  How exactly would you write the conversion within the existing query?  This is for SQL Server.  Thanks.

```
select [$Table].[field1] as [field1],
...,
[$Table].[createdon] at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time' as [createdon],
...,
[$Table].[fieldN] as [fieldN]
from [dbo].[TableA] as [$Table]
```

Comment: _... results in a type text_ No it does not. Your expression generates a column of type "datetimeoffset". So it can be restated in two ways. First, how to "use" that datatype in your coding environment. Second, how to convert your datetimeoffset to datetime. Search on the latter and you can find many discussions.

Comment: @SMor not sure if your are familiar with power bi. But I am using native query to import the table.  The data for  the createdon field does seem like it is of datetimetimezone offset.   However in power bi it’s stating that it’s of type text.  I tried converting it to type datetime but it’s not allowing me because I am using a native query and by converting that after the query is not allowed.  So I’m trying to see on that native query how I can convert to a date time after offsetting.

Comment: Can you add a column in Power Query that would do the conversion?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld no because I am using direct query and a lot of transformations I can’t do.   I was able to figure it out.  In the native query I had to add a cast keyword and convert it as date type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the conversion by using the cast keyword and convert as a date type.